# Android IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for retrofit2.Call<wh3>

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard

I have encountered the following runtime exception with my android application having upgraded from AGP `7.4.2` to `8.2.0-alpha07`

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for retrofit2.Call<wh3>
     for method MyApplicationServiceApi.siteUserLogin
    at retrofit2.Utils.methodError(SourceFile:5)
    at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.createCallAdapter(Unknown Source:12)
    at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(Unknown Source:67)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(Unknown Source:18)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Unknown Source:24)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Unknown Source:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
    at $Proxy2.siteUserLogin(Unknown Source)
    at m03.siteUserLogin(Unknown Source:2)
    at k03$k.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:47)
    at kl.resumeWith(Unknown Source:11)
    at mk0.run(Unknown Source:123)
    at f42$a.run(Unknown Source:3)
    at fb4.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at oa0.J(Unknown Source:0)
    at oa0$c.d(Unknown Source:14)
    at oa0$c.p(Unknown Source:28)
    at oa0$c.run(Unknown Source:0)
    Suppressed: mj0: [androidx.compose.ui.platform.s@839caba, ro@23c2d6b, z24{Cancelling}@53820c8, n@5931561]
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Return type must be parameterized as Call<wh3><ErrorBody, ResponseBody> or Call<wh3><out ErrorBody, out ResponseBody>
    at ep0.a(Unknown Source:194)
    at ep0.get(Unknown Source:33)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextCallAdapter(Unknown Source:35)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.callAdapter(Unknown Source:1)
    at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.createCallAdapter(Unknown Source:0)
    ... 16 more
```

I am testing my signed release build with

```
buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
```

I do not understand why increasing the AGP version to 8+ has now resulted in my release build crashing.

what additional pro guard configuration does AGP 8+ require to enable my release build to run ok?

additional refactors i have made at the same time are

```
increase android version from 33 to 34
refactored my gradle groovy build files to kts
increase kotlin version from 1.8.10 to 1.8.21
```

Comment: Try first using AGP 8.0.2 instead as that is the last stable release. Also please check where you are using Call and make sure the arguments match as the return type must be parameterized as Call<wh3><ErrorBody, ResponseBody> or Call<wh3><out ErrorBody, out ResponseBody>

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this runtime crash by adding

```
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class kotlin.coroutines.Continuation
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class arrow.retrofit.**
```

to my pro guard rules